Variance of sum of differently weighted random variables with different variances and correlations?
I want to compute:
$Var[\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_iX_i]$, where $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\overline{X_i},\sigma_{i}^2)$ are joint normally distributed and $Cov[X_i,X_j]=\rho_{ij}\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}$.
I would like to generalize/adapt to my case the following derivation for equal $\rho,\sigma,w$ for all $X_i$ (from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388663/variance-of-sum-of-dependent-random-variables):
\begin{eqnarray*}
Var\left[w^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right] & = & w^2\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}Var(X_{i})+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i\ne j}^{n}Cov(X_{i},X_{j})\right]\\
 & = & w^2\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma^{2}+\sigma^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i\ne j}^{n}\frac{Cov(X_{i},X_{j})}{\sigma^{2}}\right]\\
 & = & w^2\left[n\sigma^{2}+\sigma^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i\ne j}^{n}\rho\right]\\
 & = & w^2\left[n\sigma^{2}+\sigma^{2}(n^{2}-n)\rho\right]\\
 & = & w^2\sigma^2n\left[1+\rho(n-1)\right].\\\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
\end{eqnarray*}
I think I cannot get rid of the sum in my generalized case, but I would like to at least rewrite $Var[\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_iX_i]$ as explicitly as possible.
Moreover, how does the derivation simplify if I assume $\sigma_i=\sigma$ for all $X_i$?

$Var(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n Var(w_i X_i)+2 \sum_{1\le i<j\le n} Cov(w_i X_i,w_j X_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n w_i^2 Var(X_i)+2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n w_i w_j Cov(X_i,X_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n w_i^2 \sigma_i^2+2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n w_i w_j \rho_{ij}\sigma_i\sigma_j$.
